# Scala: Why's implicit ExecutionContext not found by implicitly?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, scalatest

I've a trait:

```
trait Crawler {
  implicit def system: ActorSystem

  implicit def executionContext: ExecutionContext

  implicit def materializer: Materializer

  // other methods
}
```

And a test class:

```
class CrawlerSpec extends AsyncFlatSpec with Matchers with Crawler {
  override implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("ufo-sightings")

  override implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = implicitly[ExecutionContext]

  override implicit val materializer: Materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  // test
}
```

According to Scalatest [doc](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/async_testing):

> Asynchronous style traits extend AsyncTestSuite, which provides an
>   implicit scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext named executionContext.

But the test blows up with a NPE due to the `ExecutionContext` being null (should fail gracefully, but that's another matter).

```
java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:494)
```

Why isn't the implicit `ExecutionContext` picked up?

```
<rant>
  Implicit resolution is a nightmare. At the expense of saving a few 
  keystrokes, it makes code so fragile that removal of a single
  import breaks it. There's a reason other statically typed languages like
  Haskell or Kotlin don't have it; it's a stinking mess.
</rant>
```

Comment: Remove the implicit keyword from the class and trait and see if it compiles.

Comment: @pedrofurla It won't, methods in the trait need an implicit ec.

Comment: Do you see how that answer your question?

Comment: I think that rant is a bit unnecessary. Implicits were created for type-classes provision, and allow for stuff like type-class derivation and type-level programming. AS far as I can tell, they are usually not used for plain-old dependency injection and passing things though the arguments by hand is still a thing in Scala world. However, I agree they are often poorly explained, sometimes overused and as there is more than one thing done, by `implicit` keyword (implicit `def`, `val`, `class`, argument are slightly different beasts) they might be confusing for people new to the concept.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok as far as I can see, nothing stops one from explicitly converting one type from another. Anyway, that's not the point of this question, so I'll leave it here.

Comment: If implicits are unnecessary, why don't you go ahead and pass all implicits explicitly?

Answer (score 4):

Let's see what happens here:

```
trait A {
  implicit def executionContext: ExecutionContext
}
```

you declare here that `A` would provide implicit value. Then

```
class B extends A {
  override implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = implicitly[ExecutionContext]
}
```

So what does happen here?

1. value `executionContext` is initialized during `B` construction.
2. then `implicitly` tries to find a value with `ExecutionContext` type.
3. it finds such value: `executionContext`.

So effectively you did something like:

```
class B extends A {

  val executionContext: ExecutionContext = executionContext
}
```

You created circular dependency on initialization: you are initializing value with itself. So you take a value though a "getter" returning a property that is still `null` (as it is just being initialized).

I agree, that implicits are concepts are something that requires a lot of effort, though I would not antagonize them as much as you. Here you had a problem with circular dependency on initialization. It cannot fail gracefully, anything other than `Exception` would put the program into invalid state.

Solution would be initializing you `implicit` value without the usage of `implicitly`. Just put some value there by hand. Or don't use that trait and import implicit from somewhere else.

Comment: Can you help me understand where the circular dependency is coming from? Shouldn't the RHS of an assignment statement be evaluated first, and when it's evaluated, find the implicit EC provided by the `AsyncFlatSpec`?

Comment: There is an order in which compiler looks through the implicits in scope: here you overshaded one provided by `AsyncFlatSpec` with one provided by `CrawlerSpec`. It's more or less closer in scope takes predecession. Hard to get closer than "the same nesting level".