# Can't decode subclasses using Circe in Scala

Tags: json, scala, enums, traits, circe

I have a Scala project in which I am using Circe to handle json.
I am having trouble decoding from JSON to subclasses of a hierarchy.

The code I am having trouble with is the following test:

```
  test("FailingResponse - Conversion between case object and Json works") {
    val caseObject = FailingResponse("Some Error", StatusCodes.INTERNAL_ERROR)
    val jsonString = caseObject
      .asJson
      .printWith(Printer.noSpaces)

    decode[ValuationResponse](jsonString) must be(Right(caseObject))
  }
```

**I want to be able to decode to any of the subclasses of ValuationResponse, since at the point of decoding I can't know for sure if the response is a FailingResponse or a SuccessfulResponse. I would like for the decoder to be able to induce what type of ValuationReponse it is, decode it and make it available as "generic" ValuationResponse. Which I could then manipulate with a match-case or something like that to get to the actual specific type.**

Instead, what I get on that test is a DecodingFailure error. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code for the hierarchy:

```
sealed trait ValuationResponse {
  def statusCode: StatusCode
}

case class SuccessfulResponse(values: List[StockValuation], symbol: String, function: TimeSeriesType, statusCode: StatusCode) extends ValuationResponse

case class FailingResponse(reason: String, statusCode: StatusCode) extends ValuationResponse

case class ValuationRequest(function: TimeSeriesType = TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY, symbol: String, interval: IntraDayInterval = IntraDayIntervals.MIN_5)

object derivation {

  implicit val encodeResponse: Encoder[ValuationResponse] = Encoder.instance {
    case response@SuccessfulResponse(_, _, _, _) => response.asJson
    case response@FailingResponse(_, _) => response.asJson
  }
  implicit val decodeResponse: Decoder[ValuationResponse] =
    List[Decoder[ValuationResponse]](
      Decoder[SuccessfulResponse].widen,
      Decoder[FailingResponse].widen
    ).reduceLeft(_ or _)

  implicit val encodeRequest: Encoder[ValuationRequest] = Encoder.instance {
    case response@ValuationRequest(_, _, _) => response.asJson
  }
  implicit val decodeRequest: Decoder[ValuationRequest] =
    List[Decoder[ValuationRequest]](
      Decoder[ValuationRequest].widen
    ).reduceLeft(_ or _)
}
```

These are the enums it uses ( Yeah I know having a enum for status codes is silly ahah):

```
sealed abstract class TimeSeriesType(val text: String) extends EnumEntry {}

sealed abstract class IntraDayInterval(val text: String) extends EnumEntry {}

object TimeSeriesFunctions extends Enum[TimeSeriesType] with CirceEnum[TimeSeriesType] {
  val values: immutable.IndexedSeq[TimeSeriesType] = findValues

  case object TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY extends TimeSeriesType("TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY")

  case object TIME_SERIES_DAILY extends TimeSeriesType("TIME_SERIES_DAILY")

  case object TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY extends TimeSeriesType("TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY")

  case object TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY extends TimeSeriesType("TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY")

}

object IntraDayIntervals extends Enum[IntraDayInterval] with CirceEnum[IntraDayInterval] {
  val values: immutable.IndexedSeq[IntraDayInterval] = findValues

  case object MIN_1 extends IntraDayInterval("1min")

  case object MIN_5 extends IntraDayInterval("5min")

  case object MIN_15 extends IntraDayInterval("15min")

  case object MIN_30 extends IntraDayInterval("30min")

  case object MIN_60 extends IntraDayInterval("60min")

}

object StatusCodes extends Enum[StatusCode] with CirceEnum[StatusCode] {
  val values: immutable.IndexedSeq[StatusCode] = findValues

  case object SUCCESS extends StatusCode(200)

  case object INTERNAL_ERROR extends StatusCode(500)

  case object REQUESTER_ERROR extends StatusCode(400)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tested your code with a few modifications (removed few things to make code compile easier):

```
  type StatusCode = Int
  sealed trait ValuationResponse {
    def statusCode: StatusCode
  }

  case class SuccessfulResponse(succ: String, statusCode: StatusCode) extends ValuationResponse

  case class FailingResponse(reason: String, statusCode: StatusCode) extends ValuationResponse

  case class ValuationRequest(test: String)

  object derivation {

    implicit val encodeResponse: Encoder[ValuationResponse] = Encoder.instance {
      case response@SuccessfulResponse(_, _) => response.asJson
      case response@FailingResponse(_, _) => response.asJson
    }
    implicit val decodeResponse: Decoder[ValuationResponse] =
      List[Decoder[ValuationResponse]](
        Decoder[SuccessfulResponse].widen,
        Decoder[FailingResponse].widen
      ).reduceLeft(_ or _)

    implicit val encodeRequest: Encoder[ValuationRequest] = Encoder.instance {
      case response@ValuationRequest(_) => response.asJson
    }
    implicit val decodeRequest: Decoder[ValuationRequest] =
      List[Decoder[ValuationRequest]](
        Decoder[ValuationRequest].widen
      ).reduceLeft(_ or _)
  }

  val caseObject = FailingResponse("Some Error", 200)
  val jsonString = caseObject
        .asJson
        .printWith(Printer.noSpaces)
```

I got

```
@ decode[ValuationResponse](jsonString)
res21: Either[Error, ValuationResponse] = Left(DecodingFailure(CNil, List()))
```

However, when I imported implicits from object

```
@ import derivation._
import derivation._

@ decode[ValuationResponse](jsonString)
res23: Either[Error, ValuationResponse] = Right(FailingResponse("Some Error", 200))
```

Thing is, by default Circe uses discrimination field to distinguish between sum type members. You can see what your value is encoded into if you don't import `derivation` object:

```
@ {
  val jsonString = (caseObject : ValuationResponse)
        .asJson
        .printWith(Printer.noSpaces)
  }
jsonString: String = "{\"FailingResponse\":{\"reason\":\"Some Error\",\"statusCode\":200}}"
```

So, you used automatically derived codecs when you decoded your case class - if you removed `import io.circe.generic.auto._` your compilation would fail when you tried to decode things without importing codes you yourself wrote (`import derivation._`).

To avoid such situations in the future:

- don't import `io.circe.generic.auto._` on production on codecs use site - it makes it possible to derive new codec for case class that should use your hand-written/manually-derived codec (which leads to bugs like this one)
- prefer `io.circe.generic.semiauto._` to summon derived codecs in place where you need them (instead of `Decoder[A]` write `deriveDecoder[A]`)
- put your semi-automatically derived codecs as well as hand-written codecs in companion objects of types for which you derive codecs (if possible) - this will remove the need to import them manually each time you need them

```
  import io.circe.generic.semiauto._

  sealed trait ValuationResponse ...
  object ValuationResponse {
    implicit val decodeResponse: Decoder[ValuationResponse] =
      List[Decoder[ValuationResponse]](
        deriveDecoder[SuccessfulResponse].widen,
        deriveDecoder[FailingResponse].widen
      ).reduceLeft(_ or _)
  }
```

BTW. usage of semiauto also helps you avoid other bugs, like [cyclic-dependency on initialization of your implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742394/scala-whys-implicit-executioncontext-not-found-by-implicitly) in your code you have:

```
@ derivation.decodeRequest.decodeJson("test".asJson)
java.lang.NullPointerException
  ammonite.$sess.cmd7$.<clinit>(cmd7.sc:1)
```

but if it used `deriveDecoder`:

```
implicit val decodeRequest: Decoder[ValuationRequest] =
    List[Decoder[ValuationRequest]](
      deriveDecoder[ValuationRequest].widen
    ).reduceLeft(_ or _)
```

you would get:

```
@ val decodeRequests: Decoder[ValuationRequest] =
      List[Decoder[ValuationRequest]](
        io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveDecoder[ValuationRequest].widen
      ).reduceLeft(_ or _)
decodeRequests: Decoder[ValuationRequest] = io.circe.generic.decoding.DerivedDecoder$$anon$1@30570f04

@ decodeRequests.decodeJson("test".asJson)
res9: Decoder.Result[ValuationRequest] = Left(DecodingFailure(Attempt to decode value on failed cursor, List(DownField(test))))
```

Comment: Well, after doing those changes you suggested, the decoding works. But while encoding I get: 
An exception or error caused a run to abort. 
java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at io.circe.syntax.package$EncoderOps$.asJson$extension(package.scala:10)
 at eventbus.ValuationRequest$.$anonfun$encodeRequest$1(eventBusCases.scala:36)

line 36 being:     case response@ValuationRequest(_, _, _) => response.asJson

Comment: The issue is now solved. I had to change on Valuation request to:
object ValuationRequest {
  implicit val encodeRequest: Encoder[ValuationRequest] = deriveEncoder[ValuationRequest]
  implicit val decodeRequest: Decoder[ValuationRequest] = deriveDecoder[ValuationRequest]
}

The recurssiveness of asJson was giving the troubles apparently.